# (Event reminder) Exclude Participant who registered after the event!

Tags: civievent, scheduling

In some occasions we had some event participants who just turned up on the events without registering. A schedule reminder is already in place for registered participant, day before the event.

Now for those who registered after the event they also receives an email after. Is there a way to excluded those participants?

Comment: I am having the same problem.  It is incredibly confusing to users to receive the schedule reminder after the event is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I can think of is to switch off the confirmation email once the event date is up? This can obviously be done manually, or you could create a little extension with a scheduled job that does this on a daily basis?