# Stop scheduled reminders for an event after the event is finished

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders

We occasionally have participants get registered for an event by our back-office staff while the event is in progress or even after it is finished.  Our events have scheduled reminders set for 1 day and 1 hour before the event.  These people who are registered during or after the event do get these scheduled reminders sent to them and it is both confusing to them and spammy of us to send them.

Six years ago [someone asked if there was a way to turn this off](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/697/event-reminder-exclude-participant-who-registered-after-the-event).  I'm hoping that in six years maybe there has been some progress or changes.

Is it possible to get scheduled reminders that are set to "XX time before the event starts" to not fire once the event start time has passed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a outstanding PR's for the fix which needs some feedback on test,

- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20432
- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19973

Comment: Awesome!!  Thank you!